# Getting `ssh client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` on ipv6

Tags: ssh, ipv6, sshd, asus

I started getting `ssh client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe` on **ipv6** after some inactivity time on ssh after my ISP switched to **ipv6**.

While on **ipv4**, I could ssh to any server and the connection would keep alive with the default configs.

I tried to set `ServerAliveInterval 60` in the client and it improved a bit, but I'm still getting disconnected after some hours. The target server/sshd is with the default config.

With the ssh verbose enabled, I get all keeplive packets every 60 seconds as follows:

```
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
```

I'm not sure if this is related, but I have bridge connection between my ISP modem and my Asus RT-AC3200 Router. My ipv6 connection type in my router is set to `Native`

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: Having the same issue for some time now, didn't notice that my ISP switched to IPV6, too which seems to cause the problem.

Comment: And what is the solution? I have exactly the same issue. Also with ssh -vvv the same error message.
If I ssh from a VM within my MacOS, the problem is gone.